# Limit of an inverse function

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

If I do not go astray, given the function $f : (0,\,4) \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $f(x) := \frac{2}{x} + \log\sqrt{x}$,  it follows that $\begin{aligned} \lim_{y \to 2} \frac{f^{-1}(y)-1}{\log(y-1)}\overset{H}{=} \lim_{y \to 2} \frac{\left(f^{-1}\right)'(y)}{\frac{1}{y-1}} = (2-1)\,\left(f^{-1}\right)'(2) = \frac{1}{f'(1)} = -\frac{2}{3} \end{aligned}$.

On the other hand, writing:

```
f = 2/# + Log[Sqrt[#]] &;

Limit[(InverseFunction[f][y] - 1)/Log[y - 1], y -> 2]
```

I get $\infty$, while writing:

```
f[x_?(0 < # < 4 &)] = 2/# + Log[Sqrt[#]] &;

Limit[(InverseFunction[f][y] - 1)/Log[y - 1], y -> 2]
```

I do not get any results. What am I doing wrong?

---

I believe it is appropriate to do some 'clarity.

Given the function $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $f(x) := \frac{2}{x} + \log\sqrt{x}$, i.e. defining in MMA:

```
Clear[f]; f[x_] := 2/x + Log[Sqrt[x]]
```

it is clear that this **is not** an invertible function and then the following graphs are entirely bogus:

[image]

Now, given the function $f : (0,\,4) \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $f(x) := \frac{2}{x} + \log\sqrt{x}$, i.e. defining in MMA:

```
Clear[f]; f[x_ /; (0 < x < 4)] := 2/x + Log[Sqrt[x]]
```

it is clear that this **is** an invertible function and the following graphics correspond to those predicted by theory:

[image]

In particular, by writing:

```
InverseFunction[f][2.]
```

I get $1.$ and by writing:

```
InverseFunction[f]'[2.]
```

I get $-0.666667$ confirming the results calculated above (on that there was no doubt of course, just apply the theory). Unfortunately, though, MMA seems to not be able to calculate the limit and that's why I started this thread.

Comment: The L'Hospital's rule is not applicable in the limit under consideration because one has no  indeterminacy $\frac 0 0$ as bbgodfrey explains.

Comment: You are right. Then, maybe, in this case the inverse function $f^{-1}$ is not OK in Mathematica.

Comment: @Manu I read your moderator flag.  I had a little difficulty understanding it, but I took the action that seemed appropriate.  Please let me know if I misunderstood you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have a slightly different approach that might be worth considering for this problem. The solution to the given limit can be found directly by looking at the series expansion of the function around $y=2.$ Generally it is possible to find the inverse of a function's series expansion with `InverseSeries`. For the function in this problem the series of $f^{-1}\left(y\right)$ around $y=2$ is given by:

```
InverseSeries[Series[2/x + Log[Sqrt[x]], {x, 1, 4}], y]
(*1-(2 (y-2))/3+14/27 (y-2)^2-4/9 (y-2)^3+(890 (y-2)^4)/2187+O[y-2]^5*)
```

Now, letting $g\left(y\right) = \frac{f^{-1}\left(y\right)-1}{\log\left(y-1\right)}$, the limit, $\lim_{y \to 2} g\left(y\right)$, can be found with:

```
Limit[(Normal@InverseSeries[Series[2/x+Log[Sqrt[x]],{x,1,2}],y]-1)/Log[y-1],y->2]
(*-(2/3)*)
```

---

**Note**

- In the limit, the result is independent from the number of terms in the inverse series.

This result can be verified for some series of various orders:

```
Table[Limit[(Normal@InverseSeries[Series[2/x+Log[Sqrt[x]],{x,1,n}],y]-1)/Log[y-1],y->2],{n,1,10}]
(*{-(2/3),-(2/3),-(2/3),-(2/3),-(2/3),-(2/3),-(2/3),-(2/3),-(2/3),-(2/3)}*)
```

Diving a bit deeper into the limit shows the independence of the result from the order of the inverse series. Due to the indeterminacy of the limit as $y \to 2$, L'Hospital's is a good choice. If we differentiate the numerator of $g\left(y\right)$ we obtain:

```
D[InverseSeries[Series[2/x + Log[Sqrt[x]], {x, 1, 3}], y] - 1, y]
(*-(2/3)+(28 (y-2))/27-4/3 (y-2)^2+O[y-2]^3*)
```

Now looking at the denominator of $g\left(y\right)$ and differentiating:

```
D[Log[y - 1], y]
(*1/(-1 + y)*)
```

Putting these two results back together to assembly our new limit:

```
-(2/3)+(28 (y-2))/27-4/3 (y-2)^2+O[y-2]^3/(1/(1-y))
(*2/3-(10 (y-2))/27+8/27 (y-2)^2+O[y-2]^3*)
```

We can now take the limit directly to get the expected result:

```
Limit[-(2/3)+(10 (y-2))/27-8/27 (y-2)^2+O[y-2]^3,y->2]
(*-(2/3)*)
```

---

***A Numerical Solution***

If we are just interested in a numeric result we can directly find the limit using an `InverseFunction` object. Specifically, using `NLimit` in the `NumericalCalculus` package:

```
Needs["NumericalCalculus`"]
NLimit[(InverseFunction[
    ConditionalExpression[2/#1 + Log[Sqrt[#1]], 0 < #1 < 4] &][y] - 
  1)/Log[y - 1], y -> 2]
(*-0.666667*)
```

Note that in this framework we need to explicitly define the domain of `InverseFunction` to obtain the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`ConditionalExpression`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ConditionalExpression) to choose the branch used by [`InverseFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InverseFunction):

```
if = InverseFunction[ConditionalExpression[2/# + Log[Sqrt[#]], #<4]&];
if[2]
```

> 1

Then, you can use [`Series`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Series) to obtain your limit:

```
Series[(if[x]-1)/Log[x-1], {x, 2, 0}] //TeXForm
```

> $-\frac{2}{3}+O\left((x-2)^1\right)$

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a bug in `InverseFunction` in your case. Compare the outputs of

```
Table[{y, FindRoot[y == 2/x + Log[Sqrt[x]], {x, 1}]}, {y, 1.5, 4,  0.1}]
```

> {{1.5, {x -> 1.56883}}, {1.6, {x -> 1.39521}}, {1.7, {x -> 
>       1.26332}}, {1.8, {x -> 1.15844}}, {1.9, {x -> 
>       1.07234}}, {2., {x -> 1.}}, {2.1, {x -> 0.938111}}, {2.2, {x -> 
>       0.884399}}, {2.3, {x -> 0.837231}}, {2.4, {x -> 
>       0.795401}}, {2.5, {x -> 0.757995}}, {2.6, {x -> 
>       0.724304}}, {2.7, {x -> 0.693768}}, {2.8, {x -> 
>       0.665939}}, {2.9, {x -> 0.640453}}, {3., {x -> 
>       0.617011}}, {3.1, {x -> 0.595364}}, {3.2, {x -> 
>       0.575303}}, {3.3, {x -> 0.556652}}, {3.4, {x -> 
>       0.539261}}, {3.5, {x -> 1.}}, {3.6, {x -> 0.507759}}, {3.7, {x -> 
>       0.49344}}, {3.8, {x -> 0.479958}}, {3.9, {x -> 
>       0.46724}}, {4., {x -> 0.455219}}}

and

```
Table[{y, NSolve[y == 2/x + Log[Sqrt[x]], {x}]}, {y, 1.5, 4, 0.1}]
```

> {{1.5, {{x -> 1.56883}, {x -> 15.5229}}}, {1.6, {{x -> 1.39521}, {x ->
>         20.1069}}}, {1.7, {{x -> 1.26332}, {x -> 
>        25.6351}}}, {1.8, {{x -> 1.15844}, {x -> 32.3403}}}, {1.9, {{x ->
>         1.07234}, {x -> 40.497}}}, {2., {{x -> 1.}, {x -> 
>        50.4353}}}, {2.1, {{x -> 0.938111}, {x -> 
>        62.5557}}}, {2.2, {{x -> 0.884399}, {x -> 
>        77.3456}}}, {2.3, {{x -> 0.837231}, {x -> 
>        95.3993}}}, {2.4, {{x -> 0.795401}, {x -> 
>        117.442}}}, {2.5, {{x -> 0.757995}, {x -> 
>        144.357}}}, {2.6, {{x -> 0.724304}, {x -> 
>        177.227}}}, {2.7, {{x -> 0.693768}, {x -> 
>        217.369}}}, {2.8, {{x -> 0.665939}, {x -> 
>        266.396}}}, {2.9, {{x -> 0.640453}, {x -> 326.275}}}, {3., {{x ->
>         0.617011}, {x -> 399.409}}}, {3.1, {{x -> 0.595364}, {x -> 
>        488.733}}}, {3.2, {{x -> 0.575303}, {x -> 
>        597.832}}}, {3.3, {{x -> 0.556652}, {x -> 
>        731.084}}}, {3.4, {{x -> 0.539261}, {x -> 
>        893.838}}}, {3.5, {{x -> 0.523001}, {x -> 
>        1092.63}}}, {3.6, {{x -> 0.507759}, {x -> 
>        1335.42}}}, {3.7, {{x -> 0.49344}, {x -> 1631.98}}}, {3.8, {{x ->
>         0.479958}, {x -> 1994.19}}}, {3.9, {{x -> 0.46724}, {x -> 
>        2436.6}}}, {4., {{x -> 0.455219}, {x -> 2976.96}}}}

Maybe, an unappropriate choose of the solution causes it. A workaround is suggested in another answer.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is appropriate to do some 'clarity.

**1.** Given the function $f : (0,\,+\infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $f(x) := \frac{2}{x} + \log\sqrt{x}$, i.e. defining in MMA:

```
Clear[f]; f[x_] := 2/x + Log[Sqrt[x]]
```

your graph is trivially the following:

[image]

from which it is clear that $f$ is a continuous function but **not injective and therefore even invertible** in the entire domain. On the other hand, if you appropriately restricts the domain, you can consider two separate injecting and then inverse functions.

As specified in the official guide, in these cases *InverseFunction[]* can represent **only one of the possible inverse function** and that remembers him with a warning. In particular, by defining the function generally as shown above, you are obtained by the inverse for $x \ge 4$ and actually writing:

```
Quiet[InverseFunction[f][2.]]
```

I get $50.4353$ without any warning. This having been established, for $x \ge 4$ gives the following graphs:

[image]

**2.** Given the function $f : (0,\,4) \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $f(x) := \frac{2}{x} + \log\sqrt{x}$, i.e. defining in MMA:

```
Clear[f]; f[x_ /; 0 < x < 4] := 2/x + Log[Sqrt[x]]
```

on the basis of what has just been said it is evident that it is a continuous function and **injective in its own domain, then also invertible**. In particular, by writing:

```
InverseFunction[f][2.]
```

I get $1.$ without any warning. In the latter case, the respective graphs are as follows:

[image]

In this other case, also writing:

```
InverseFunction[f]'[2.]
```

I get $-0.666667$ confirming that the limit in question is actually equal to $-2/3$ (on that there was no doubt of course, just apply the theory). Unfortunately, though, MMA seems to not be able to calculate the limit and that's why I started this thread.

*In light of this, I would say that there is no bug, but it is yet another confirmation that Ferrari is not enough to win a race car, but also need a good driver, which still are not and these are the biggest mistakes in where it is likely to incur. Peace.*